Connection between table seo_url and table product_category in Shopware6
is it possible, connecting table seo_url with table product_category by Query? If yes, which tables have to be joined?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Understand this first and update your query according to user perspective.

Use the combination of foreign_key and route_name when joining.
SELECT *
FROM seo_url su
LEFT JOIN product p ON p.id = su.foreign_key AND su.route_name = 'frontend.detail.page';

With this query, you get the SEO URLs of product details pages and the corresponding product data.
